# String literal is not properly closed by double quote

Tags: java

Getting the error in the title, while texting on eclipse. How to escape "\" (probably) or Should I switch to whatsapp?

```
  if(fileUploader.getFilename().subSequence(0, 12).equals("C:\fakepath\"))
    fileName = fileUploader.getFilename().substring(12,
            fileUploader.getFilename().length());
```

Comment: *Should I switch to whatsapp?* What does that mean?

Comment: @Jens: And the first one... I doubt the OP really wants a form feed.